# Making Percentage Bar Map

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, grid, square, waffle-chart

I'm sorry I don't know what to call these kind of chart. I've already made a square grid map, rectangle located on every centroid. (pic 1)

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPSIl.jpg)

Now I want to make like a percentage map (isotype?), but I don't know how to do it. (pic 2--photoshopped)

[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlvLv.jpg)

This is the code, I modified it from a simple map code

```
d3.json(url).then(function(dataset){

  group = canvas.selectAll("g")
    .data(dataset.features)
    .enter()
    .append("g")

  areas = group.append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("class","area")
    .style("fill","white")
    .style("opacity",0)
    ;

  group.append("rect")
    .attr("x",function (d) { return path.centroid(d)[0];})
    .attr("y",function (d) { return path.centroid(d)[1];})
    .attr("width",10)
    .attr("height",10)
    .style("fill","orange");


});
```

I already have an idea, by manually adding the data on the JSON, but I want to know how to do it from dynamic input. I want to google it but don't have any clue or keyword.
Thanks

Comment: can you add your code to the question, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman Hi, I already edited my post, hope it explain